# Use of “conscience” as verb

Tags: verbs, errors

I’ve heard *conscience* used as a verb, in the phrase *can’t conscience*. For example,

> I can’t *conscience* taking credit for what I didn’t do.

Is this use of *conscience* correct? From a Google search it appears this phrase is actively used, but I can’t find it in the OED or other dictionaries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you are encountering misuse of the word *conscience* by people who have an imperfect memory of a phrase such as “I can’t *countenance*” or “I can’t *condone*”.

> **coun·te·nance** /ˈkountn-əns/ Verb: Admit as acceptable or possible. (Google)
>
> **con·done** /kənˈdōn/ Verb:   Accept and allow (behavior that is considered morally wrong or offensive) to continue. Approve or sanction (something), esp. with reluctance. (Google)

Comment: While I agree this may be the origin of the phrase, why can't conscience be used as verb meaning "to be with knowledge of something"? Countenance means like "one's appearance or face" and to countenance means "admit as acceptable" in that it means "to look upon with favor", the root of countenance means "to contain or hold together", when I say to "I can't conscience a thing" I mean I can't understand it and thus can not accept it as true or as knowledge. For instance, "I can't conscience a relationship with you" means "I don't know you."

Comment: I actually think the right word is "to conscion", but some say it is "archaic" meaning no one taught them about it in time for them to feel they should know it, I guess, so I will accept conscience (v.) or conscion until such time as we undeprecate conscion.

Answer (score 3):

*[Conscience](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscience)* is not a verb. It is a noun; ergo it should be treated as such. That usage of *conscience* is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, conscience cannot legitimately be used as a verb.  They probably meant to say (or are deliberately shortening):

> I can’t *in good conscience* take credit for what I didn’t do.

Comment: Did you mean it can't be used as a verb?

Comment: @BarrieEngland: At least that's what I thought -- not a verb.

Comment: Err yeah - verb.  Oops.

Comment: English has a grammatical process called zero-derivation that enables the conversion of a noun to a verb with no overt morphology. This allows English speakers to use any noun as a verb if they so wish. So while it may be that this particular case is an error (e.g. if the speaker intended another word and produced this one by mistake), English speakers are legitimately able to do this if they wish. The meaning is certainly clear.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut: That reminds me of this comic: http://www.unmemorabletitle.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/calvin-and-hobbes.jpg

Comment: I think it is used as a verb like "beknow with".

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut
"Words are also actions, and actions are a kind of words." Emerson

Answer (score -1):

As a linguist I would say the claim of correctness is applicable if and only if it is derived from common usage. The native speakers of a language themselves decide what is correct or incorrect via their usage of the language. It is for this reason that a language can be said to be “alive.”

There exist certain grammatical rules derived from Latin which were unsuccessfully imported into the English language in the mid-1800’s. These rules, including “no split infinitives,” and “no ending a sentence with a preposition” have *never* taken hold in English, and would serve only to reduce the viability and flexibility of the English language in its efforts to express a universe of thought. English stylists, and grammarians are largely disenfranchising such rules upon consideration that they have no bearing in any real-world dialect of English.

Any time you use an existing English word modified by legitimate grammatical practices, and native speakers of English understand what you are saying, then you have legitimately conveyed an idea to another person by means of the English language, and therefore have used the English language appropriately.

The word *conscience* is in regular usage as a verb, along with all of its derived forms, and hence ought to be considered a legitimate word in the modern English language. Consider also the undisputably legitimate form *unconscionable*. *Conscionable* means “able to be conscienced.” How can it therefore be legitimate, lest its definition also be legitimate?

Comment: OEtymD derives *conscionable* not from a verb *conscience* but from *conscioned* "having a conscience". Where are you getting your facts?

Comment: What @MetaEd said. According to Google, the only current instance of ["able to be conscienced"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22able+to+be+conscienced%22&oq=%22able+to+be+conscienced%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.23311406&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is in fact this answer. Which I therefore think is *wrong*.